# Who decides the venue for ODI matches?

Tags: cricket, officiating, venues

Who decides the match venue of One Day International cricket matches: ICC or the Country cricket boards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cricket board of the country which is hosting the series, will discuss with the local cricket boards to decide the venues for the matches.

You can refer [this link](http://www.cricketcountry.com/news/west-indies-cricket-boards-to-decision-pull-out-guyana-as-venue-condemned-145280) for reference, that the cricket board of West indies made the venue decision for the ongoing test against NewZealand.(same for ODIs too).

You can also refer [this](http://www.cricket.com.au/news-list/2013/9/11/ca-announce-2014-15-test-venues), that the cricket board of Australia made decisions about the venues for the matches which they are going to host on 2014/15.